# Extracting error logs from Windows event viewer

Tags: windows, vbscript, ftp, event-viewer

I want to create `VBScript` code to retrieve specifically error type logs from Windows Event Viewer, save them in a `.txt` file, and transfer it via FTP or just direct copy.

How can I achieve this?

I've been doing some reading and stumbled upon these pages:

[Main question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0edeb332-5e66-4b03-9957-b4d076e0406f/vbscript-to-pull-only-errors-from-the-event-log-on-a-remote-computer?forum=ITCG), [Eventquery.vbs info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490900.aspx) and [Copy file to remote computer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/557bdbcb-6ff3-4a01-a660-17fa99d732bb/copy-file-to-remote-machine?forum=ITCG).

But I just don't understand how to do this process as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the Event Log using a WMI query.  Here is information about the [specific class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/eventlogprov/win32-ntlogevent).

Without knowing exactly what you're looking for, let's assume you wanted to search the Application event logs and record any event id 1003. I use On Error Resume Next as a quick fix so it doesn't error out if a field doesn't contain data.

```
On Error Resume Next
LOG_FILE = "temp.txt"

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Application'")

For Each objEvent in colItems
    If objEvent.EventCode = 1003 Then       
        writeLog "Category: " & objEvent.Category
        writeLog "Category String: " & objEvent.CategoryString
        writeLog "Computer Name: " & objEvent.ComputerName
        writeLog "Data: " & objEvent.Data
        writeLog "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode
        writeLog "Event Identifier: " & objEvent.EventIdentifier
        writeLog "Insertion Strings: " & objEvent.InsertionStrings
        writeLog "Logfile: " & objEvent.Logfile
        writeLog "Message: " & objEvent.Message
        writeLog "Record Number: " & objEvent.RecordNumber
        writeLog "Source Name: " & objEvent.SourceName
        writeLog "Time Generated: " & objEvent.TimeGenerated
        writeLog "Time Written: " & objEvent.TimeWritten
        writeLog "Type: " & objEvent.Type
        writeLog "User: " & objEvent.User 
        writeLog ""  
    End If
Next

Sub writeLog(strText)
  Dim objFSO, objLogFile
  
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
  Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LOG_FILE, 8, True)

  objLogFile.WriteLine strText
  objLogFile.Close
  
  Set objLogFile = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily do this by launching power shell.

A simple way to filter event logs for errors in powershell is

```
Get-EventLog -LogName APPLICATION -EntryType Error
```

You could easily make this a part of batch script or vbscript if needed.

To re-direct it to a text file, yon can use the following:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName APPLICATION -EntryType Error > Result.txt
```

Then, you need to upload the text file to FTP

Answer (score 1):

In Event Viewer, you can go to Custom Views, **Administrative Events** on the left.  It has Critical, Error, and Warning (level 1,2, and 3) events from 72 different logs (the windows api has a 256 logname query limit).  I assume these are the most important logs.  You can click "Save All Events in Custom View As..." on the right, and pick your format:  evtx, xml, txt, or csv.  I get about 4000 events on my computer.

If you're willing to dig into powershell, you can search *all* logs for errors since a certain time with a foreach loop.  "-ea 0" is short for "-erroraction silentlycontinue".

```
$a = get-winevent -listlog * | foreach { get-winevent @{ 
  logname = $_.logname;
  starttime = '5/2/2020 12:53 pm'; level = 1,2,3 } -ea 0 } |
  where message -match 'whatever' 
$a.count
67

$a | export-csv file.csv
```

Answer (score -2):

this line

For Each objEventin colItems

must correct like this
For Each objEvent in colItems

Comment: This is not an Answer. You should post it in comment under QuickNull's answer.